# Increment operation as a parameter in while loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
  int a;
  a=1;
  while(a++<=2)
    ;

  printf("%d",a);
}
```

This code gives the output as 4.
How is `a` getting incremented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How does `a++` work?

First things first, let's understand what happens when you type `a++`. What you are using is called a *post* [increment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators). To explain its behavior, one can look at the *"verbose equivalent"*:

```
prev_a = a;
a = a + 1;
return prev_a;
```

Note that the value returned by the `a++` expression is the value it had before the increment.

On the other hand, if you had written `++a`, you would be using a *pre* increment operator, which returns the value after increment. Kind of like:

```
a = a + 1;
return a;
```

So when you write `a++ <= 2`, you are comparing the current value of a, and incrementing it *"after comparison"*, for the next iteration.

---

### How does `while` work?

Now when you write something like `while (expr) { /* ... */ }`, what happens is that `expr` is evaluated **before every iteration**,  and the iteration actually runs only if the result of the expression is `true`.

---

### So what happens?

1. First iteration

   - `a` is equal to `1`;
   - it is smaller or equal to `2`: we decide go for another iteration;
   - increment `a`;
2. Second iteration

   - `a` is equal to `2`;
   - it is smaller or equal to `2`: we decide go for another iteration;
   - increment `a`;
3. Second iteration

   - `a` is equal to `3`;
   - it is **not** smaller or equal to `2`: we decide to stop after this iteration;
   - **still increment `a`**, as part of *"evaluating the whole expression `a++ <= 2`"*;

In the end, `a` is equal to `4`.

I guess what tricked you is the fact that the previous value of `a` (before increment) is used for comparison, but that the increment does always happen as part of the expression. `a` is being incremented, even if the comparison returns `false`!

In the end, your code is equivalent to:

```
int a;
a = 1;

int prev_a;
while(true) {
    prev_a = a; // the previous value is saved for the comparison
    a = a + 1;  // the increment ALWAYS happen
    if (prev_a > 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How is a getting incremented?

`a` is increased by the `a++` in `while(a++<=2);`.

`a++` will return the value of `a` and add one to it, so when `a` is 3, `a++<=2` will be false, but `a` still get added by one.

Answer (score 0):

When `a=3` we have `a++<=2` i.e. `3++<=2` - hence it becomes 4 at the end of the statement even though the condition fails. You could have simply put a `printf` to check this:

```
while(a++<=2)
{
     printf("%d ",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2 iteration the value of `a` is 2. So the condition is true and the value is incremented again i,e a=3.

Now the while condition is checked again and it returns false. But a is incremented again as `(3++<=2)` so a=4

Answer (score 0):

```
init_stat  execute    status  result

a =1    while(a++<=2) success  a =2
a =2    while(a++<=2) success  a =3
a =3    while(a++<=2) fail     a =4
```

Comment: The last line should be `a =3`? :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the condition of the loop `(a++<=2)` evaluated by 3 times.

1st time: a is 1, and a <= 2, and then a -> 2 by `operator++`
2nd time: a is 2, and a <= 2, and then a -> 3  by `operator++`
3rd time: a is 3, and a **not** <= 2, and then a-> 4 by `operator++`